# What is the name of a removable button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

Sometimes when I am using freelance websites, I often come across the section of Choose your skills with the ability to search for skills then clicking on them. Once you click the skills, the skill is added to your "inventory" of skills in an oval button like shape. However, if you added a wrong skill, you can hover over the skill and click on the (x) part of the button to remove it. It is also used in stackoverflow when you want to add the tags to your question.

I am interested in doing something similar to this, however I soon realized that I don't even know what this "button" or feature is called hence my question. I have added a picture of it for reference.

[image]

Comment: It's just called close icon. See Bootstrap https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/close-icon/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a Label with close icon in Bootstrap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390272/how-to-create-a-label-with-close-icon-in-bootstrap)

Comment: Take a look at [this link](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#multiple) hope it will help

Comment: In the Material design guidelines, it's called a "[chip](https://material.io/guidelines/components/chips.html)"

Comment: Thanks Everyone, I now know its name and have a rough idea about how I'll do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<form action="" id="tag">
    <select multiple="true" name="select[]" id="select" class="form-control select2">
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Script**

```
$('#select').select2({
    tags: true,
    tokenSeparators: [",", " "],
    ajax: {
        url: "time.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: function (term, page) {
             return {
                  q: term, // search
                  page: page
             };
             },
    results: function (data, page) {
        return { results: data};
    }
}
});

   $('#tag').submit(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $.ajax({
      url: "test.php",
      type  : 'POST',
      dataType : 'json',
    // serialize the form:
    data     : $('#tag').serialize(),
    success  : function(response){
    //handle data
    }
  });
});
```

**php code**

```
<?php
  if(isset($_GET['select']){ //check if there is vlaue
    foreach($_GET['select'] as $key => $value){
   }
  }
  ?>
```

*Note : it will work for select2 version 4.0*

Hope this might help as i used this for one of my website , and it worked for me , what function you required actuall requires ajax and jquery i have given both script and php of my page  and yeah do not forget to link jquery script before calling this script

Answer (score 0):

That is called as multi select and can be easily implemented via a plugin known as `select 2`.

just include `select 2 css` and `select 2 js` and you are good to go like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".js-example-basic-multiple").select2();
</script>

<select class="js-example-basic-multiple" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    ...
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

Refer this link for demo and info

https://select2.github.io/examples.html

Hope this helps